# Sample size for large population with rare events?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, small-sample

I want to calculate what fraction of the US population,  say 300M, responded to a commercial shown on TV based on a small sampling of data.     I think only about 100,000 will respond,   0.0003%

How to I choose a sample size that would be enough to calculate this number,  +/-10% with 90% confidence?

Or alternately,  if I have a sample size of 1 million,   how well will I be able to estimate the response rate?